# Mongoose freezes on find when there is too many results

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to implement a find in Mongoose. Everything works until there is too many records in the database. In my case, there are 8 records in the NewSchema collection. Do anyone know why this is happening?

My Sample Code:

```
var NewSchema = new Schema({
  asd : String,
  sdf : String,
  dfg : String,
  fgh : String,
  bnmxcv : [String],
  klj : String,
  sdfsdf : String,
  wer : String,
  uio : Date
});

var New = mongoose.model('NewSchema', NewSchema);

New.find({asd:_id},
              function(err, list) {
  /////// IT FREEZES HERE ////////
});
```

Comment: Does it "freeze" in your callback (where you have the comment) or does the callback not get called? Can you show what the code inside your callback is?

Comment: 8 doesn't seem like it could be "too many" in any context.

Comment: Yes, I don't think its "too many" at all also, but it freezes any way. When I meant that it freezes, the callback doesn't get called. I tried adding a console.log in the callback function, the message never got printed.

Comment: By the way, I am running Node.js and MongoDB on a micro ec2 instance.

Comment: Did you get this to work? I've got the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

You should also register the schema to Mongoose before trying to use it, try the following code:

```
var NewSchema = new Schema({
  asd : String,
  sdf : String,
  dfg : String,
  fgh : String,
  bnmxcv : [String],
  klj : String,
  sdfsdf : String,
  wer : String,
  uio : Date
});

var NewSch = mongoose.model('NewSchema', NewSchema);

NewSch.find({asd:_id}, function(err, list) {
  // do stuff
});
```

Comment: Hi sorry for the misunderstanding, I actually have that piece of code already, I just forgot to copy it into my question above. But it still didn't work.